# How can I enforce a maximum number of children in a node?

Tags: firebase

How can I enforce a maximum number of children of a node using a security rule?

```
/bar/customers/$customer/drinks_ordered
```

Should not have more than fifteen children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might seem like you could use a numeric id for the ordered drinks and then try something like this; it will fail since the ID is a string:

```
"$customer_id": {
    "drinks_ordered": {
       "$drink_id": {
          ".validate": "$drink_id > 0 && $drink_id < 16" // error
       }
    }
}
```

Instead, you can use a counter and validate the counter to be 1-15, and then validate the drink ID matches the counter.

```
"$customer_id": {
    "counter": {
       // counter can only be incremented by 1 each time, must be a number
       // and must be <= 15
       ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() > 0 && newData.val() <= 15 && ((!data.exists() && newData.val() === 1) || (newData.val() === data.val()+1))"
    },
    "drinks_ordered": {
       // new record's ID must match the incremented counter
       "$drink_id": {
          // use .val()+'' because $drink_id is a string and Firebase always uses ===!
          ".validate": "root.child('bar/customers/'+$customer_id+'/counter').val()+'' == $drink_id"
       }
    }
}
```

Naturally, your drinks will look something like this:

```
 /bar/customers/george_thorogood/counter/3
 /bar/customers/george_thorogood/drinks_ordered/1/burbon
 /bar/customers/george_thorogood/drinks_ordered/2/scotch
 /bar/customers/george_thorogood/drinks_ordered/3/beer
```

Now before a client could add another drink, they would have to set the counter to 4 (which is the only thing it can be set to) and then add the drink with that same ID.

A little roundabout, but it does do the job : )

Comment: I also attempted the first example. It would be convenient to have it supported.

The counter method is clever!

Comment: I struggled with this because I kept getting an error about `.val` not being valid.  Problem was with validation sample.  Should be :   ` ".validate": "root.child('/bar/customers/' + $customer_id+'/counter').val()+'' == $drink_id"`, right?

Comment: You could also just make the id a string padded with initial zeroes and then just validate $drink_id >= '00' && $drink_id < '16'  ...right?

Comment: I'm not sure that > and < will work as expected with strings, since it's going to be a lexicographical comparison and not a numeric one. For example, 100 would come before 11