# Enforce maximum number of children at Firebase node (on the server)

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Is there a way to enforce (on the **server**) a maximum number of children for a Firebase node? The only answers I've seen have been [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14925830/4639555) and [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16345415/4639555).

For my use case, each child absolutely **must** have a unique ID, so I can't use a ring buffer or any other approach that involves "cheating" with numeric keys. Client-side validation isn't enough - never trust the client, after all!

If this isn't possible - it seems like a pretty major feature to be missing!

Comment: Is this two questions?  1) (have the server) enforce a max number of children in a node   2) how to ensure each child in 1) has a unique ID?

Comment: I know how to generate a unique ID -- the Firebase API has a `push` function that does so. I was just specifying that because of the need for unique IDs, I can't use the ring buffer solution.